# Having problem with regular expression in twig?

Tags: php, regex, twig

I wantS to change `src=""` value to be empty if `src="assets/js/asd2323/script.js"`

with regex in twig src value not empty. it has script src

I don't want to empty all my src attribute values within my loops :|

```
{% for script in site['scripts'] %}
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    {% if script['src'] == matches '{(script.js)}' %}

    {% else %} 
         src="{{ script['src'] }}"
    {% endif %}
    >
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for this just use

```
{% if not ('script.js' in script['src']) %}
    <script src="{{ script['src'] }}"></script>
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/a5n59d)

Comment: i dont want to empty all my script src need to empty only one that at the end have only 
script.js  -->>   "/assets/js/asdcas4456/script.js

Comment: Updated, parantheses seemed to be required in here. See demo

Comment: Thank you soo much @DarkBee :)